# SQL getting values and then total count of those values

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
I am working on an auction script with a table that looks like the attached image.

Within an auction two users can place the same bid amount, for example two players could place a bid of '1' which would give that bid amount a total count of two.

I need a query which gets all of a users single bid amount along with the total count of that bid amount within the scope of the auction id.

As it stands I first get the users bids:

```
SELECT bid_amount FROM all_bids WHERE auction_id = '129' AND user_id = '9'
```

And then I am looping through each amount in PHP and doing the following

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_bids WHERE auction_id = '129' AND bid_amount = 'xxx'
```

But this is of course very power hungry and I am sure it can be done all in one query.

I have got as far as

```
SELECT bid_amount,COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT bid_amount FROM all_bids WHERE auction_id = '129' AND user_id ='9') as foo GROUP BY bid_amount
```

Which returned the correct bid amounts but the counts were all **1** which is wrong as I guess my incorrect query is only counting the values within the subquery and not outside of the bids that just that user placed

Comment: Your sample data has no auction "123" nor player_id column.  This makes your question hard to follow.  Also tag the question with the database you are using and explain the error.

Comment: That table is huge with thousands of bids so it is hard to give a snapshot to specify but I understand your points

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT  a.*, b.cnt from all_bids a 
 join (select bid_amount,COUNT(*) cnt from all_bids group by bid_amount) b 
 on a.bid_amount=b.bid_amount
 WHERE a.auction_id = '123' AND a.player_id = '456'
```

Comment: Tried and just get NULL results, SQL throws an error that a table 'bid_amount' does not exist which is strange as the table name is 'all_bids'

Comment: You absolute hero! Thank you so much, that is spot on! Made my day!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `group by`:

```
select bid_amount, count(*)
from all_bids 
where auction_id = 123 and player_id = 456
group by bid_amount;
```

Note that you do not need single quotes for a numeric constant.

Hmmm. You might want this phrased as:

```
select ab.bid_amount, count(*)
from all_bids ab
where ab.auction_id = 123 and
      ab.bid_amount in (select ab2.bid_amount
                        from all_bids ab2
                        where ab2.auction_id = ab.auction_id and ab2.player_id = 456
                       )
group by ab.bid_amount;
```

Comment: SQL error 'at line 4' according to phpmyadmin unfortunately